# Appending to a Laravel route in an href with JS

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, append, href

I have the following route in my div tag.

```
    <div class="clickable-element col-lg-3 col-md-6 location-tile js- 
   location-id" data-href="{{ route('report.file.details', 'id') }}">
    <div>Content</div>
    </>
```

How can I use JS to append the end of the route?

My JS builds an object and with the location id name etc. This is what I have but I receive an error saying I'm missing a parameter in my route.

```
$LocationTile.find('.js-location-id href').attr('href').append(this.locationid);
```

Answer (score 0):

The attr tag does not inherently get data elements, only the data tag does that. You need to start by changing `.attr('href')` to `.attr('data-href')` or `.data('href')` depending on version of Jquery you are using.

Also, can you share what `LocationTile` is. Is it another Jquery element? As well as what `this` represents. Are you looping elements?